# Is it possible to dynamically allocate 2-D array in c with using calloc() once?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic

All the solutions I have seen online has calloc() function used twice, is it possible to do with only using it once?
The below code is not printing the correct array elements

```
int **ptr;

//To allocate the memory 
ptr=(int **)calloc(n,sizeof(int)*m);

printf("\nEnter the elments: ");

//To access the memory
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{  
 for(j=0;j<m;j++)
 {  
  scanf("%d",ptr[i][j]);
 }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your code is, how does the pointer know the dimensions of your array? It needs those dimensions to calculate the correct memory address. That's why it only works directly with one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) @Lundin Hammer time

Comment: @Stargateur I try to avoid dupe-hammering to questions/answers posted by myself, unless they are community wikis or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C99 you can use pointers to VLAs (Variable Length Arrays):

```
int n, m;

scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

int (*ptr)[m] = malloc(sizeof(int [n][m]));

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{  
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {  
        scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j]); // Notice the address of operator (&) for scanf
    }
}
free(ptr); // Call free only once
```

Comment: What if m,n are defined at runtime?

Comment: That's the purpose of VLAs, you can set it at runtime, edited in order to reflect that.

Comment: Since C11 VLA are optionnel ;)

Comment: Notably, this code actually doesn't use a VLA, but a pointer to VLA. The C11 committee were confused and failed to see the benefit of pointers to VLA, which is important in modern C programming. Unlike actual allocated VLAs, which are much less useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about minimising the number of calls to memory allocation functions you can created such a jagged array like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ** alloc_jagged_2d_array_of_int(size_t n, size_t m)
{
  int ** result = NULL;
  size_t t = 0;

  t += n * sizeof *result;
  t += n*m * sizeof **result;

  result = calloc(1, t);
  if (NULL != result)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      result[i] = ((int*) (result + n)) + i*m;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ** alloc_jagged_2d_array_of_int(size_t, size_t);

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  int ** p = alloc_jagged_2d_array_of_int(2, 3);
  if (NULL == p)
  {
    perror("alloc_jagged_2d_array_of_int() failed");
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
      {
        p[i][j] = (int) (i*j);
      }
    }
  }

  /* Clean up. */

  free(p);

  return result;
}
```